# can I scale my part in solidworks using a design table, but without scaling through any sketches?

Tags: solidworks

title says it all.. scaling in solidworks with design tables usually involves providing the table with all the dimensions of the sketch, then producing alternate configurations within the table.  is there a way to instead specify the overall scaling of the part?  right now, I'm creating new parts for each different scaling (there aren't -that- many.. so far..)

Edit:  I think this is the answer:  https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/79957

Comment: Why wouldn't you use formulas?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat  ..you need to be more specific.  use formulas in what context?  what I'm trying to avoid through this question is having to input all the different dimensions of all the sketches into the design table in the first place..

Answer (score 1):

When you are Smart Dimensioning, if you enter ="R", SW will create a global variable "R", which can be used in equations to redimension as required as long as you use "R" in the new dimensions as formulas.

In this case, I am making a circle with dimension "R".  I do not care what R actually is.

[image]

SW puts sigma before the dimension to indicate it is a equation:

[image]

and adds the Equation box to the part tree.

[image]

So if I add a second circle with Smart Dimension ="R"*2, I get a second circle sized based upon the dimension "R".

[image]

[image]

Right mouse click on Equations and you can manage Equations.  Notice I have changed R to 40 and both are scaled.  This is how I handle scaling.  Usually I adjust a fey key variables and I get good results.  Start simple.

[image]

Comment: hi, I'm not quite sure how I should respond to this.  I thank you very much for your efforts in providing an answer!  I've learned something!  my clarification of my original question was inadequate.  what I'm really looking for is a way of avoiding having to dimension -any- of the sketches.  say I create a swept boss using a spline with a ton of points.  I don't want to dimension each one.  I just want to scale the whole thing using a design table.  I see I added a note to my original question that gives a site that presumably I concluded had the answer..

Comment: No problem.  Hard to do sketches without dimensions.